# YouTube video content covering CSS drop down menus in IE < 9

Tags: css, youtube

I've created drop down menus using CSS and I have a YouTube video placed in a box just below my nav bar. When using IE 8, the drop down menus fall behind the YouTube video, despite the fact that the div with the nav bar has a higher z-index than the div with the YouTube video. The problem does not exist in Firefox, Safari or IE9.

You can see the problem by going to the web site:

http://www.mensdiscipleshipnetwork.com

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It looks like you need to add `?wmode=transparent` to the YouTube embed `iframe src` url. Like so:

```
<iframe width="632" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/_K-YwgCyg70?wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I get a "Error occurred. Try again later." message

Comment: The URL needs to be `http://www.youtube.com/embed/_K-YwgCyg70?wmode=transparent`. @sdleihssirhc: For future info.

Comment: Thank you! This fixed my problem. I really appreciate the help for a newbie.

Comment: Thank you! I was wondering why the issue occurs for some of IE11 users but not for all. The only difference I noted was that the affected users were running the IE11 on Windows 7. Windows 8 users did not have the issue.

Answer (score 3):

You can add that parameter automatically to all iframes src like so:

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('iframe').each(function()
        {
               var url = $(this).attr("src");
                var char = "?";
              if(url.indexOf("?") != -1)
                      var char = "&";

                $(this).attr("src",url+char+"wmode=transparent");
        });
    });
```

Comment: Be careful - this will amend ALL iframes on your page, when you only need to target YouTube iframes. You should target there the src url includes the youtube domain.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using *embed*, wmode needs to be an attribute rather than part of the URL `wmode="transparent"`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the iframe API you can add it like this (note the last param in the playerVars object):

```
player = new YT.Player(playerID,
        {
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%',
            videoId: vidID,
            playerVars: {
                controls: 2,
                autohide: 1,
                showinfo: 0,
                modestbranding: 1,
                wmode: 'transparent'
            }
        });
```