# YouTube Video Embedded via iframe Ignoring z-index?

Tags: css, iframe, youtube

I'm trying to implement a horizontal multilevel dropdown navigation menu. Immediately below (vertically) the menu, I've got a YouTube video embedded via iframe. If I hover over one of the main level nav items in Firefox, the dropdown menu properly appears *on top of* the video.

In  Chrome and IE9, however, only a sliver of the dropdown is visible in the small region of space I have between the menu and the iframe.  The rest of it seems to be *behind* the iframe.

The problem seems to be related to the YouTube video, *not* the iframe. To test, I aimed the iframe at another web site rather than the video, and the dropdown menu worked fine, even in IE.

- Question 1: WTF?
- Question 2: Why, even if I explicity put a `z-index:-999 !important;`
  on the iframe does this problem still occur?

Is there some internal CSS that the YouTube embed code includes that is somehow overriding things?

Comment: Can you post a link - it's difficult to give a helpful response without code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [z-index and iFrames!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281002/z-index-and-iframes)

Comment: possible duplicate of [YouTube video content covering CSS drop down menus in IE < 9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747133/youtube-video-content-covering-css-drop-down-menus-in-ie-9)

Comment: for anyone wondering how this works in 2015, the `<embed  wmode="transparent" ...>` section is all you need (at least in firefox) and no need to worry about setting wmode in `url`'s `param`'s or `iframe`s

Comment: keep in mind that for some reason there are two different types of youtube links: http://www.youtube.com/v/video_id and http://www.youtube.com/embed/video_id. The v-link ignores z-index in IE, but embed works fine.

Comment: +1 for a beautifully written question; It is difficult to find users -writers, even- with this quality of conciseness.

Comment: Theoretically, putting a `z-index:-999 !important` on the iFrame does not make sense as it **contains** the content that you are trying to hierarchically separate it from; for this reason it will not differentiate.

Answer (score 244, accepted):

Try adding wmode, it seems to have two parameters.

```
&wmode=Opaque

&wmode=transparent
```

I can't find a technical reason why it works, or much more explanation but [take at look at this query](http://www.google.co.uk/webhp?rlz=1C1SKPM_enGB448GB448&sourceid=chrome-instant&ix=heb&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#q=youtube%20wmode&hl=en&rlz=1C1SKPM_enGB448GB448&site=webhp&prmd=imvns&ei=RyYnT-zlH8LQ0QXJ16HOCg&start=0&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=a8cc55938fdce19c&ix=heb&ion=1&biw=1920&bih=936).

```
<iframe title="YouTube video player" width="480" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/lzQgAR_J1PI?wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" wmode="Opaque">
```

or this

```
//Fix z-index youtube video embedding
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('iframe').each(function(){
        var url = $(this).attr("src");
        $(this).attr("src",url+"?wmode=transparent");
    });
});
```

Comment: (I'm the OP)  Thanks everyone!  I stumbled upon a similar solution at http://manisheriar.com/blog/flash_objects_and_z_index  The key seems to be using both name="wmode" value="transparent" on a <param> *and* wmode="transparent" on the <embed>.  As I suspected, it's not an iframe issue.  It seems to be an issue with Flash wanting (demanding?) the highest z-index unless you force it to be transparent.

Comment: If you're using the iframe JS API a playerVar `wmode` also works although it's not documented.

Comment: I have integrated this and my fancybox stil doesnt work in ie7/8 and I still get the video on top. http://www.encompasscu.com.au/homeiswheretheheartis    what can I do

Comment: The ?wmode=transparent option worked like a charm for me.  I only wish I was faster at finding the right question to ask.  24 hours after I started looking I found this answer.  Thanks for answering and posting the query above as well!

Comment: Not able to see video when i click on Play only sound is coming but video is not visible, but while i do full screen video is able to visible on android PHONE GAP

Comment: @Dan, see my edit... you might already have a query string in your youtube embed code.  (like ?rel=0 to not show relevant videos).  If that's the case use &wmode=transparent (or opaque - I've heard opaque uses less system resources, so I use that mainly, unless I have a reason to make it transparent).

Comment: what works for me is:  `.........?rel=0&wmode=transparent`   and `wmode="transparent"`

Comment: Good point. I implemented this fix amongst several sites and it corrected the issue. Is there any documentation on why this is needed with IE ?

Comment: I had an issue with the embedded youtube video via iframe was overlapping my fixed navigation bar, no matter what z-indexes I added. The wmode attribute on the iframe and url parameter worked a charm! Thanks!

Comment: I tried the above and the document onload didn't work for me, but Richard M's comment above did.

Comment: Also add `position: relative;` to container what need to cover your video. That help a lot.

Answer (score 29):

*Joshc*'s answer was on the right track, but I found that it totally deletes the `?rel=0` querystring and replaces it with the `?wmode=transparent` item - which has the effect of displaying the YouTube Suggested Videos list at the end of the playback, even though you originally didn't want this to happen.

I changed the code so that the `src` attribute of the embedded video is scanned first, to see if there is a question mark `?` in it already (because this denotes the presence of a pre-existing query string, which *might* be something like `?rel=0` but could in theory be anything that YouTube choose to append in the future). If there's a query string already there, we want to preserve it, not destroy it, because it represents a setting chosen by whoever pasted in this YouTube video, and they presumably chose it for a reason!

So, if `?` is found, the `wmode=transparent` will be appended using the format: `&mode=transparent` to just tag it on the end of the pre-existing query string.

If no `?` is found, then the code will work in exactly the same way as it did originally (in *toomanyairmiles*'s post), appending just `?wmode=transparent` as a new query string to the URL.

Now, regardless of what may or may not be on the end of the YouTube URL as a query string already, it gets preserved, and the required `wmode` parameters get injected or added without damage to what was there before.

Here's the code to drop into your `document.ready` function:

```
$('iframe').each(function() {
  var url = $(this).attr("src");
  if (url.indexOf("?") > 0) {
    $(this).attr({
      "src" : url + "&wmode=transparent",
      "wmode" : "opaque"
    });
  }
  else {
    $(this).attr({
      "src" : url + "?wmode=transparent",
      "wmode" : "opaque"
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: This worked for me whereas the accepted answer didn't (even after fixing the code). Thanks for the drop-in fix.

Comment: ? starts the parameter query string, & is the delimiter. Basic stuff. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667551/add-parameter-to-links-on-page-using-jquery

Comment: This fixed my problem 10 secs before giving up!

Comment: Perfect! I was looking for this for ages!

Comment: It's `opaque` not `Opaque` (note the case)

Answer (score 6):

Just add one of these two to the src url:

```
&wmode=Opaque

&wmode=transparent

<iframe id="videoIframe" width="500" height="281" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxxx?rel=0&wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 5):

I have the same problem on YouTube iframe embeds only in internet explorer though.

Z-index was being ignored totally, or the flash video was just appearing at highest index possible.

This was what I used, slight adapting the above jquery script.

**My embed code, straight from YouTube...**

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/QldZiR9eQ_0?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

**The jQuery slighty adapted from the above answer...**

```
$('iframe').each( function() {
    var url = $(this).attr("src")
    $(this).attr({
        "src" : url.replace('?rel=0', '')+"?wmode=transparent",
        "wmode" : "Opaque"
    })
});
```

Basically if you don't select **Show suggested videos when the video finishes** in your embed settings, you have a `?rel=0` at the end of your `"src"` url. So I've added the replace bit in case `?rel=0` exists. Otherwise `?wmode=transparent` won't work.

Answer (score 2):

We can simply add `?wmode=transparent` to the end of YouTube URL. This will tell YouTube to include the video with the wmode set. So you new embed code will look like this:-

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/C4I84Gy-cPI?wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
```

Comment: This was already suggested in many answers here no need to repeat it with yet another answer. If you have something new to add please do, otherwise please don't just repeat what others already posted.

Answer (score 2):

Only this one worked for me:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var frames = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
    for (var i = 0; i < frames.length; i++) {
        src = frames[i].src;
        if (src.indexOf('embed') != -1) {
        if (src.indexOf('?') != -1) {
            frames[i].src += "&wmode=transparent";
        } else {
            frames[i].src += "?wmode=transparent";
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I load it in the footer.php Wordpress file. Code found in comment [here](http://www.daddydesign.com/wordpress/fixing-youtube-iframe-z-index-using-jquery/)  (thanks Gerson)

Answer (score 1):

wmode=opaque or transparent at the beginning of my query string didnt solve anything. This issue for me only occurs on Chrome, and not across even all computers. Just one cpu.  It occurs in vimeo embeds as well, and possibly others.

My solution to to attach to the 'shown' and 'hidden' event of the bootstrap modals I am using, add a class which sets the iframe to 1x1 pixels, and remove the class when the modal closes. Seems like it works and is simple to implement.

Answer (score 1):

The answers abow didnt really work for me, i had a click event on the wrapper and ie 7,8,9,10 ignored the z-index, so my fix was giving the wrapper a background-color and it all of a sudden worked. Al though it was suppose to be transparent, so i defined the wrapper with the background-color white, and then opacity 0.01, and now it works. I also have the functions above, so it could be a combination.

I dont know why it works, im just happy it does.

Answer (score 1):

BigJacko's Javascript code worked for me, but in my case I first had to add some JQuery "noconflict" code. Here's the revised version that worked on my site:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $j = jQuery.noConflict(); 
jQuery(document).ready(function($j){
  $j('iframe').each(function() {
    var url = $j(this).attr("src");
      if ($j(this).attr("src").indexOf("?") > 0) {
        $j(this).attr({
          "src" : url + "&wmode=transparent",
          "wmode" : "Opaque"
        });
      }
      else {
        $j(this).attr({
          "src" : url + "?wmode=transparent",
           "wmode" : "Opaque"
        });
      }
   });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need on the iframe is:

```
...wmode="opaque"></iframe>
```

and in the URL:

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/123?wmode=transparent
```