# youtube video sits above all other content ignoring wmode

Tags: jquery, youtube, fancybox, z-index

I am asking this question of the back of a post a year or so ago.

[YouTube Video Embedded via iframe Ignoring z-index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9074365/youtube-video-embedded-via-iframe-ignoring-z-index)

I have a you tube video on a page. on that page I want to show a fancybox.. but due to the youtube video this doesnt work

I have added in the code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function (){
    jQuery('iframe').each(function(){
        var url = jQuery(this).attr("src");
            if (jQuery(this).attr("src").indexOf("?") > 0) {
                jQuery(this).attr({
                  "src" : url + "&wmode=transparent",
                  "wmode" : "Opaque"
                });
            }
    });
});
```

and that will get added to the code

```
<iframe width="500" height="281" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/TUNROkqBte4?theme=light&showinfo=0&modestbranding=0&border=0&fs=1" frameborder='0'></iframe>
```

which i cannot change.

why would this still be happening in ie7/8 with the added jquery?

Thanks

Comment: change "src" : url + "&wmode=transparent", to "src" : url + "&wmode=opaque",

Comment: no joy- thanks though

Comment: Is it only happening in IE7/IE8?

Comment: Have you tried lowering the z-index of the container of the iframe, and raising it for fancybox? Or setting them at all?

Comment: yes.. its just happeneing with youtube vids

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the youtube's URL format :

```
http://www.youtube.com/v/...
```

... is not the proper one to be used within an `iframe` tag.

The proper format for `iframe` should be :

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/...
```

If you cannot change it, then replace it on the fly using the javascript `.replace()` method like :

```
jQuery('iframe').each(function () {
    var url = jQuery(this).attr("src").replace(new RegExp("/v/", "i"), '/embed/');
    if (jQuery(this).attr("src").indexOf("?") > 0) {
        jQuery(this).attr("src", url + "&amp;wmode=opaque");
    }
});
```

That should do the trick. See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/VdQWY/)**