# iframe in FireFox not respecting z-index

Tags: css, firefox, iframe, cross-browser

I have a YouTube video embedded in my site (in an iframe) and I also have a menu that is triggered by jquery to pop up over the page. This works fine in Chrome, but in FireFox the iframe appears over the top of the menu.

I tried setting the iframes z-index to less then the pop up boxes,  eg:

```
iframe {
position: absolute;
z-index: 10;
}

#popup {
position: absolute;
z-index: 99;
}
```

but that didnt change anything - the iframe still appears over the pop up box.

Would anyone know a way to deal with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding wmode, it seems to have two parameters.

```
&wmode=Opaque
&wmode=transparent

<iframe title="YouTube video player" width="480" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/lzQgAR_J1PI?wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" wmode="Opaque">
```

For more info
check

[YouTube Video Embedded via iframe Ignoring z-index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9074365/youtube-video-embedded-via-iframe-ignoring-z-index)