# CSS3 Transition on absolute positioned element disappears under Canvas, Embed

Tags: html5-canvas, css-transitions, zurb-foundation

I have a menu bar with drop downs that use absolute positioned elements. On hover, the elements fade in using CSS3 transitions. Note, we're using a heavily modified version of Zurb's Foundation 4.

```
.has-dropdown {
    .dropdown {
        z-index: 90;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    }
    &.hover .dropdown {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

We have an instance of an [OpenSeadragon](http://openseadragon.github.io) image, using the html5 `<canvas>` option on one page, and a YouTube `<embed>` on another. The YouTube embed has the `wmode="Opaque"` and `&wmode=transparent` code on them to force them to respect z-index as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9074365/youtube-video-embedded-via-iframe-ignoring-z-index). Both the embed and the canvas and their parent elements are set to `z-index: 2; position: relative;`

The issue we're running into is that the .dropdown element drops behind the `<canvas>` and the `<embed>` once the transition is complete. This seems to happen mostly on Chrome. As soon as we mouse over any of the menu items, the menu pops back in front.

How do we fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing the transition fixed the issue. The menu popped right in front of both the canvas and the embed and stayed there.

This didn't solve the issue with having a css transition, though. In order to fix that, I applied a `webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);` to the .dropdown:

```
.has-dropdown {
    .dropdown {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
        opacity: 0;
        transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    }
    &.hover .dropdown {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

Now I have a transition that appears over the top of the embed and the canvas. Happy days!

Comment: I was having a similar problem, elements were hiding on webkit until hovering over them if a css transition had been applied (specifically; transform: translate3d). Adding "-webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
        opacity: 0;" to these elements fixed the issue. You sir, are a genius! Thanks.

Comment: Can someone please give an explanation on why this works?

Answer (score 0):

Just add `z-index` to higher number like:

```
z-index: 1111;
```

If needed add:

```
pointer-events: none;
```

Comment: This didn't work, one of the first things we tried. :)