# Z-index issues with iframe in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, iframe, z-index

IE seems to ignore elements with higher z-indexes, when they overlap an iframe.

Have read various other posts that suggest adding a combination of &wmode=transparent to the iframe src, and wmode="opaque" attribute to the iframe itself; though IE doesn't seem to like either of these.

```
<iframe title="YouTube video player" class="media-youtube-html5" type="text/html" width="500" height="300" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/9W82sMSMJJg?hd=1&wmode=transparent" wmode="opaque" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7fd8Y/

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does `iframe { z-index: -1; }` do anything in IE?

Comment: @misterManSam , unfortunately not.

Comment: What about if there is no z-index applied at all [like in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7fd8Y/4/). Is the badge over the `iframe` in IE?

Comment: possible duplicate of [YouTube Video Embedded via iframe Ignoring z-index?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9074365/youtube-video-embedded-via-iframe-ignoring-z-index)

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your code. Now working fine in IE, just added the wmode parameter through
 javascript
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/karan3112/q48K2/)

```
$('iframe').each(function(){
    var url = $(this).attr("src");
    $(this).attr("src",url+"?wmode=transparent");
});
```

Refer [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9074365/youtube-video-embedded-via-iframe-ignoring-z-index)

Comment: The original code had some errors which are resolved in the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Your link is wrong, the default link word should be **embed**,

```
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/9W82sMSMJJg" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

but not just **v** (v-link ignores z-index):

```
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/v/9W82sMSMJJg" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Here is an example for IE:
http://jsfiddle.net/7fd8Y/21/