# Elements overlapping on youtube video

Tags: html, css, youtube

I am having a problem on youtube videos. Other elements(LayerSlider) is overlapping on top of it. This is the link (http://havencab.com.au/). To see the bug, click that link and try to make to video fullscreen.

I came across to the below link

[YouTube Video Embedded via iframe Ignoring z-index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9074365/youtube-video-embedded-via-iframe-ignoring-z-index)

but that didnt solve. Are there any other ways to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Putting `z-index: 0;` on .ls-wp-fullwidth-container appears to fix the issue. I'm not certain why this is, maybe someone else could explain what is happening.

It might also be helpful to know that the you can open the inspect element mode while in full screen (in chrome at least) using Ctrl+Shift+C on windows