# YouTube content covers my css dropdown menu in ie 11

Tags: internet-explorer, youtube, internet-explorer-11, wmode

YouTube content covers my css dropdown menu in ie 11. I have tried various fixes that I found here and none has worked. http://www.marinwaldorf.org/ FYI I am limited in knowledge to css and html .Please advise. Thanks

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the issue: http://i.imgur.com/OKoLgsU.png.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My client sent me this screenshot of how this page renders in ie11 http://screencast.com/t/7DJaJTCrUUv8

Comment: Ah, I see now - it repros on Windows 7, but not on Windows 8.1.

Comment: Try adding `&wmode=transparent` to the end of the YouTube iframe `src` attribute.

Comment: possible duplicate of [YouTube Video Embedded via iframe Ignoring z-index?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9074365/youtube-video-embedded-via-iframe-ignoring-z-index)

Comment: Thanks. I tried this before and it didn't show as rendering when I pushed it live. Perhaps I have written it wrong? My code:<iframe width="398" height="265" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/tZmAX5adCl0?wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" padding-bottom="10px;"></iframe>

Comment: Try the following: `<iframe width="468" height="263" src="//www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/J-vjkJEClls?rel=0&wmode=transparent" frameborder="0"></iframe>`.

Comment: I just pushed that up. I don't have a way to test. Do you mind? Thanks <iframe width="468" height="263" src="//www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/J-vjkJEClls?rel=0" frameborder="0"></iframe>

Comment: You can download free virtual machines with IE 8 from http://modern.ie, or if you want something quicker, http://browserstack.com will allow you to test IE 8 from within your preferred browser/OS. I'm happy to test for you though this time; code doesn't appear to have propagated to the live server yet.

Comment: After pushing the source code renders:<iframe width="468" height="263" src="//www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/J-vjkJEClls?rel=0" frameborder="0"></iframe>

Comment: What would prevent the code from propagating?

Comment: Let's discuss this in a hangout: https://plus.google.com/hangouts/_/gxfwxpx5niokchocuzdhw77lyma

Comment: Issue resolved. It was a pleasure speaking with you Catherine!