# Div won't overlap iframe docx/pdf in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, iframe, internet-explorer-8

How do I get the green div to overlap my DOCX or PDF IFrame in `IE`? Using `z-indexes` doesn't work.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
html, body { 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
}
#container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    left: 50px;
    right: 50px;
    bottom: 25px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
}
#overlap {
    background-color: green;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 10;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <iframe height="100%" width="100%" src="Test.docx"></iframe>    
</div>
<div id="overlap">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Firstly, you should define the iframe's height in the css, not HTML, and why not try removing <div id="container"> and giving the iframe that ID instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9074365/youtube-video-embedded-via-iframe-ignoring-z-index

Comment: @Deep The duplicate appears to be for `YouTube` videos. I just put IDs on the DIVs for simplicity of styling

Comment: Which version(s) of IE are you working with?

Comment: @JonathanSampson currently IE11, but IE8+ (that I care for) all are having the same issue.

Comment: @zLan I've added the IE 8 tag to identify it as your base requirement.